# populating Django model field with databse field data

Tags: django

I have three tables in a MySQL DB. Two of the tables are pre-populated.
The 3rd table will be filled with data I enter via a Django Form. What
I want to do is populate the station_id and sku_id selections in the
labunits_uut table (via a form) with data from the labunits_resources
and labunits_sku tables - specifically the 'name' field in those tables.

Here are the table defines:

```
CREATE TABLE `labunits_resources` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    # what I want to populate the station_id form field with
    `type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cm` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `labunits_sku` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL, 
    # what I want to populate the sku_id form field with
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `labunits_uut` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `cm_serial` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `rvbd_serial` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `station_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
    `sku_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `state` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `location` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    KEY `station_id` (`station_id`),
    KEY `sku_id` (`sku_id`),
    CONSTRAINT `uut_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`station_id`) REFERENCES  
    `labunits_resources` (`id`),
    CONSTRAINT `uut_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`sku_id`) REFERENCES `labunits_sku`  
    (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Comment: So exactly what is the question here? I can see the db schema you wish to populate. But then?

Comment: Sorry! I pushed send too soon. When I put code into my question it was not formatting correctly so I pulled it. Then I sent what was left by mistake.Been writing my full query offline and was going to cut&paste. Anyway... What I'm trying to accomplish is to populate a form (specifically the station_id and sku_id via a form on an html page) from the data in the name fields in the lab_units_resources and labunits_sku. I have everything working when I just use a the following:

Comment: I have everything working when I just use a the following: station_id = models.CharField(max_length=13, choices=STATIONS, default='Choose',blank=False, null=False). I did that to get all things working. Then I wanted to modify the station_id and sku_id to get the choices from db tables instead of a static source in my code.